# 「何言わせんのよ」＝「何言わせるのよ」？

Tags: grammar, contractions

I saw this in an anime clip: the context was, "What're you making me say."

Is that simply a contraction or am I missing some conjugation or inflection here?

The first is the original and the second is what I think it could write out to...?

Comment: Some words are pronounced differently went spoken. Like how `I'm going to` can become `I'm gunna (or gonna)`. Similarly, `分からない` often becomes `分かんない` when spoken. I think the above is just a contraction or `Lazy Tongue` as my Japanese Professor used to say.

Comment: Please write answers in the answer box :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply a contraction. (Well, I am not sure what word is phonologically correct. But, this change does not change its meaning.)
We still use both expressions, but mainly left when it is pronounced.

音便 :  https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9F%B3%E4%BE%BF#.E6.92.A5.E9.9F.B3.E4.BE.BF