# Is the 帰らせん the same as 帰らせる?

Tags: words, dialects, dialogue

> 「他のプロセッサーの三倍も整備の手間をかけさせてるのもおれですが」
>
> ぐっとアルドレヒトは喉を鳴らした。サングラスの奥から苦々しげに見下ろしてくる双眸を、見返してシンは肩をすくめる。
>
> 「ったくおめぇは……たまに冗談言ったと思ったらそれかよ」
>
> 「これでも申し訳ないと思ってはいるんです。行動で示せてはいませんが」
>
> 「馬鹿野郎。お前らガキどもを生きて**帰らせん**のが整備班の仕事だ。そのために必要だってんなら機体なんざどうなろうが構やしねぇし、どんな手間だってかけてやるよ」

From
86─エイティシックス─
安里アサト

Is the bold 帰らせん the same as 帰らせる?

It’s our job to make sure you kids come back in one piece.

Comment: Related: [「何言わせんのよ」＝「何言わせるのよ」？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28621/43676), [Why is the て-form being used before ん？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61958/43676)

Comment: When 帰らせん is followed by の, なら, には, etc., you need to check the context to see if it's 帰らせるの/なら/には or 帰らせないの/なら/には. But I somehow feel someone who speaks like this would probably say 帰らせねぇのが if 帰らせないのが were intended.

Comment: (After some thinking) 食べんなら is probably 食べるなら in tough guy speech and 食べないなら in wise old man speech.